# Get position of header footer in pdf

Tags: java, pdf, coordinates, extract, pdfbox

I have a requirement where I need to get a list of coordinates of all headers and footer of all PDF pages. Is there any open source library in Java which allows me to do the same.

I have already tried using Apache-PDF Box library; but I could not find any way of identifying header and footer part

Can someone please guide me in this ? Asking help from all Java gurus here?

Comment: How can your headers and footers be identified? (You surely know that in generic pdfs there don't need to be any tags or structures identifying headers and footers as such...)

Comment: I was under impression header and footer are part of every page of pdf (even though empty). Like a template made of header footer and body

Comment: They may be on every page. But on each page they don't necessarily differ in type from regular content. And headers and footers can differ from page to page, e.g. if they contain the current page number or the title of the current chapter.

Comment: Thats alright the content may be different. But i wish to dynamically find coordinates of header and footer of a pdf.

Comment: Ok. So by which criteria can the header and footer text be recognized? As mentioned above, in generic pdfs they need not be specially marked. Thus, you need custom criteria to recognize them. If you tell us which criteria give rise to correct recognition of header and footer text in your documents, we can try and help you implement them.